# Understanding metrics within SOAP UI Load Test

Tags: soapui

I am doing some load testing within SOAP UI and want some help in understanding some of the metrics and how it works. Below is a screenshot of a load test I've completed:

Looking at the above, am I correct/incorrect on what I believe the above metrics is saying?

Limit: 100 Seconds - Does that mean the load test will last for 1 minute 40 seconds? So lets say I want the load test to last for 10 minutes, I can set that within there by setting 1000 seconds?

Min: - Is this the quickest the test step has run for? Also is it in milliseconds?

Max - Is this the longest the test step has run for? Also is it in milliseconds?

avg - Is this the average test step run? Also is it in milliseconds?

bytes - Is this how much memory taken altogether or for the latest test run?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the screenshot you are using the Simple strategy but there are of course others.

> https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/simulating-different-types-of-load.html#1-Simple-Strategy---Baseline--Load-and-Soak-Testing

The simple strategy is known for:

> The Simple Strategy runs the specified number of threads with the
>   specified delay between each run to simulate a breathing space for the
>   server. For example if you want to run a functional test with 10
>   threads with 10 seconds delay, set Threads to 10, delay to 10000 and
>   random to how much of the delay you want to randomize (i.e. setting it
>   to 0.5 will result in delays between 5 and 10 seconds). When creating
>   a new LoadTest this is the default strategy and set at a relatively
>   low load (5 threads with 1000ms delay).

The limit is I believe when your test will be cut even though it could have proceeded to take on further runs. This is the total time.

But this is only because you are using a timebased limit.
This is explained here:

> https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/creating-and-running-loadtests.html#1-1-LoadTest-Execution

To your further questions:
*min*: The shortest time the step has taken (in milliseconds)
*max*: The longest time the step has taken (in milliseconds)
*avg*: The average time for the test step (in milliseconds)
*bytes*: The number of bytes processed by the test step

I think you can read all the details here:

> https://www.soapui.org/load-testing/reference/loadtest-window.html